# How to use a MySQL database with ASP.NET site, without connecting during development time?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, mysql

I need to access and download data from a MySQL database without connecting to the database during development in VisualStudio. Is there a way to program it blindly (since I know what the database looks like) like its done in PHP?
Alternatively, can I use download the database schema and use it in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean?

Even if you can't connect to the live database during dev time, you can create your own local testing MySQL database and connect to that.

Comment: I agree, that will also help in your testing. Without connecting to a DB, you might not 'catch' some hideous bugs. Will be good also if the DB has realistic data for more 'realistic' data-related testing cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could write sql and use sql connection, and just mock out the database so that your testing will still work, as long as your mock returns what is expected.

Though I agree that creating your own local database would be best.